# Rails Rspec Capybara and DatabaseCleaner - using truncation only on feature tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, database-cleaner

I saw this cool method for only using Database cleaners :truncation for capybara test using :js => true

In spec_helper.rb:

```
config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = if example.metadata[:js]
    :truncation
  else
    :transaction
  end
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

The problem is that any feature test done with capybara seems to need the cleaning strategy to be :truncation.

All the other specs, however, are fine with :transaction, which is significantly faster.

Is there a way of specifying strategy for only capybara feature tests? SOmething like:

```
DataCleaner.strategy( :truncation ) if :type => :feature
```

Comment: I didn't need the accepted answer but your question was very useful for me!  I am using the 'if JS use truncation' block and it's working perfectly!  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. The number of hours I spent messing around with this was not fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do it, let me know

```
config.after(:all, :type => :feature) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
end
```

Comment: wouldn't you want to clean the database after auch test run?

Comment: I tried with `config.before(:suite, :type => :feature)`, but I had no luck, the `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation` is always running :/